# Consume a java REST service with .net client

Tags: c#, java, rest, compact-framework

I'm facing some problem with .net and REST by java. The scenario is: a handheld with .net compact framework 3.5 trying to consume a RESTeasy service. This is my (relevant) client code:

```
string url = textBox1.Text;
url = "http://192.168.1.77:8080/demo-rest/myresource/message";
try
{
    string json = "{id: 5, message: hello}";
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    req.ContentType = "application/json;charset=utf-8";
    req.KeepAlive = false;
    req.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
    req.Method = "POST";
    byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
    req.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
    StreamWriter postwriter = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());
    postwriter.Write(postBytes);
    postwriter.Close();
    handleResponse((HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    textBox3.Text = url + "\n" + ex.Message;
}
```

Pretty simple, but, I always got the same error: HTTP 400 Bad Request. Here is the (relevant) stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('S' (code 83)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
```

what's wrong in my client?

Comment: Are you able to issue a successful request to your REST service using any other tools? For example, directly from Firefox? And can you show us what exactly your .net client sends to the server?

Comment: BTW, using `StreamWriter` is not the best thing here, as it closes the underlying stream when you call `postwriter.Close();`. You can simply do `req.GetRequestStream().Write`.

Comment: I did the task by simply write the string, not it's UTF-8 encoded byte array. Maybe an encoding issue?

Comment: Might be an encoding issue. Try removing **charset=utf-8** from you content-type: `req.ContentType = "application/json;";`

Comment: You really need to grab the output from your HTTP request and print it to see what it looks like...